# Fair coin, three consecutive heads, p(TAILS=1)

Tags: probability

Stuck on this question.

The experiment of tossing a fair coin until three consecutive heads appear is performed. Let X be the number of tosses, and Y be the number of tails that appear. Find the probability p(Y = 1).

I tried listing out the possibilities where Y=1:

THHH
HTHHH
HHTHHH

So I thought maybe it's 3/(2^6) but that's not listed as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first toss is a T, then the event $Y=1$ happens if the first $4$ tosses are THHH. This has probability $\frac{1}{16}$.

If the first toss is a H, then $Y=1$ can happen in $2$ ways: (i) the second toss is a T and then we get HHH or (ii) the second toss is a H, the next is a T, and then we get HHH. Note that (i) has probability $\frac{1}{32}$ and (ii) has probability $\frac{1}{64}$.

Add up our three probabilities, and simplify.

**Remark:** Your idea was right, there was just a little error in computing the probabilities.

Comment: Seems to make sense to me.  Doesn't match any of the answers given, however.  (1/16 + 1/32 + 1/64 = 7/64).  Answer choices are 7/18, 3/32, 25/32, 5/6, 2/3.  Wrong sample question?

Comment: The unnecessary definition of the random variable $X$ makes me wonder whether what you have is the full question. But the probability that $Y=1$ is clear. If while solving we forgot about HHTHHH, we would get $3/32$, one of the given answers. But of course that would be wrong.

Comment: X comes into play in subsequent questions.  Don't we have to consider cases like TTTTTTTTTTHHH in the denominator?

Comment: @SeanBollin: Yes, the interpretation as a conditional probability problem is fully reasonable. However, the probability that sometime or other there will be $3$ consecutive heads is $1$, so the answer is $7/64$.